# Write two chapters on the same page

Tags: chapters, koma-script

I just have a little question. Is there a possible way to write two chapters on the same page? Thank you for your help! : )

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, titlepage]{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
\listoffigures\vfill
\pagebreak
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Tabellenverzeichnis}
\listoftables\vfill

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\KOMAoptions{listof=leveldown,listof=totoc}\addchap{Verzeichnisse}\listoffigures\listoftables`

Comment: btw. why do you add `\pagebreak`? The lists already start a new page (by using `\cleardoublepage`)

Answer (score 2):

The quick and dirty solution would be to redefine `\cleardoublepage` locally. The TOC entries however can be made with `listof=totoc` option.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, titlepage]{scrbook}

\KOMAoptions{listof=totoc}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage
{
   \let\cleardoublepage\relax
   \listoffigures
   \listoftables
}

\end{document}
```

---

A maybe cleaner solution as said by Johannes_B in the comments would be to use `listof=leveldown` so their headings will be of type `\section` and add an appropriate `\chapter` for both:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, titlepage]{scrbook}

\KOMAoptions{
   listof=totoc,
   listof=leveldown,
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\addchap{Lists}
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\end{document}
```

Using `\addchap` instead of `\chapter` prevents the number while adding a TOC entry (see the manual for more information).