# Problem with the space in align-environment

Tags: align

May someone help me? Why is there such a great space between the equal sign and the rest of the equation? I hope you see what I mean...Is there a way to shorten this? And may I also make a greater space between the lines?

Thank you for your help!

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, titlepage]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\frac{dE(G_S)}{dq_S} &= 990 - 2q_S - 0.6q _{M\textcolor{red}{_n}} - 0.4q_{M\textcolor{blue}{_h}} &= 0 \\
\frac{dG_{M\textcolor{red}{_n}}}{dq_{M\textcolor{red}{_n}}} &= 990 - q_S - 2q _{M\textcolor{red}{_n}} &= 0 \\
\frac{dG_{M\textcolor{blue}{_h}}}{dq_{M\textcolor{blue}{_h}}} &= 950 - q_S - 2q _{M\textcolor{blue}{_h}} &= 0 \\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should understang that, in this align environment, the second `&` indicates a *second* alignment group, so it is quite normal to have this distance, as alignment groups have to be separated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `{alignat*}{n}` for this case, where `n` = (number of `&` in a row + 1) / 2

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, titlepage]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{colortbl}

% more spacing in align etc.
\setlength{\jot}{2ex}

\newcommand{\indN}{\textcolor{red}{_n}}
\newcommand{\indH}{\textcolor{blue}{_h}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
\frac{dE(G_S)}{dq_S} &= 990 - 2q_S - 0.6q _{M\indN} - 0.4q_{M\indH} &&= 0 \\
\frac{dG_{M\indN}}{dq_{M\indN}} &= 990 - q_S - 2q _{M\indN} &&= 0 \\
\frac{dG_{M\indH}}{dq_{M\indH}} &= 950 - q_S - 2q _{M\indH} &&= 0 \\
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To increase the vertical spacing between the aligned lines, set the length `\jot` to a higher value. In my example the change will effect all multiline math environments. To change it just for one enclose the change in a group (pair of braces):

```
{\setlength{\jot}{2ex}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
% ...
\end{alignat*}}
```

If you use the indices more than once it would be much better to define a command for them like I did in the example.

Comment: Thank you!!! May you also help me here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297759/write-two-chapters-on-the-same-page

Comment: you might want to be more specific about the effect of `\jot` -- it affects *vertical* spacing only.

Comment: Erh don't you mean numbers of &  in a row?

Comment: As for jot, you can just use the spreadlines env from mathtools, does the same thing, just easier to read in code form

Comment: @hpz1719. You’re welcome … and done ;-)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I would, if I could ;-) actually I’m now really familiar with what `\jot` does, so pleas feel free to edit my answer a litte ;-)

Comment: @daleif: Yes you’re right, thanks for pointing that out! :-)